# How to rotate an image on an HTML5 canvas around center

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

This is practically an exact duplicate of 20 other questions, but I can't find the correct answer anywhere. All I need is a way to rotate an image around its center. I have tried this (using `strokeRect` as a placeholder):

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.rotate(-angle);
ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 150, 100);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
```

I have tried dozens of variations on this and looked at every Stack Overflow post on the topic, with no function that draws an image **rotated on its center by a certain amount.** That's all I want.

Comment: The simplest way of doing it is  drawing the rect with it's center in the origin of the canvas. In your case `ctx.strokeRect(-75, -50, 150, 100);` You need to transform the context before stroking the rect. If this is not what you need please add a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate by the desired center plus half the size of the image, rotate, then translate back by half the size of the image. Otherwise your are rotating around the corner. I used save and restore instead of rotating and translating back after the draw, because it's faster.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x + width/2, y + height/2);
ctx.rotate(-angle);
ctx.translate(-width/2, -height/2);
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: I've always heard translating it back is faster...now I'm confused!

Comment: Faster to write... and easier to maintain. I have no information to provide on the relative performance of both methods, but I have written games where save and restores were performed for every element displayed on the screen, every frame, and it never seemed to be a problem.

Comment: Misinterpreted the answer at first...might be a good idea to note that the two `0`s in the `strokeRect` are required...otherwise it was great!